# GLib-CRITICAL ошибки Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, cuda, glib

После учтановки CUDA Toolkit при запуске скрипта на Python 2.7 начали появляться странные ошибки:

(pkg-config:13085): GLib-CRITICAL **: 04:26:07.389: g_string_insert_len: assertion 'len == 0 || val != NULL' failed

(pkg-config:13234): GLib-CRITICAL **: 04:26:10.447: g_string_insert_len: assertion 'len == 0 || val != NULL' failed

После нескольких секунд скрипт запускается насколько я могу судить. Пробовал переустанавливать Python и `sudo apt-get install --reinstall libglib2.0-0 libglib2.0-bin libglib2.0-data`. Ошибки все так же появляются.